# ¿Cómo puedo alcanzar el elemento input más previo al botón presionado en Javascript y/o jQuery con varios inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Si uso la librería jQuery yo puedo alcanzar el primer `input` que está antes de cualquiera de estos dos botones:

```js
$('.my-class button').click(function() {
  var elInput = $(this).parent().parent().find('input');
  console.log(`jQuery -> Botón presionado: ${$(this).prop('id')} \nValor del input adyacente: ${elInput.val()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-class">
  <input id="ibxOne"  type="text" value="test value" />
  <button id="btnOne" type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnTwo" type="submit">Action 2</button>
</div>
```

Pero si quiero hacer lo mismo con Javascript puro no puedo.

Usando [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) puedo alcanzar el `input` al presionar el `Botón1`, pero si presiono el `Botón2` ya el `input` no es alcanzado.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class button').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var elInput = el.previousElementSibling;

    console.log(`Javascript -> Botón presionado: ${el.id} \nValor del input adyacente: ${elInput.value}`);

  }))
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <input id="ibxOne"  type="text" value="test value" />
  <button id="btnOne" type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnTwo" type="submit">Action 2</button>
</div>
```

### La pregunta

Si son varios inputs seguidos:

```
<div class="my-class">
  <input id="ibxOne"    type="text" value="test value" />
  <button id="btnOne"   type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnTwo"   type="submit">Action 2</button>
  <hr />
  <input id="ibxTwo"    type="text" value="test value 2" />
  <button id="btnThree" type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnFour " type="submit">Action 2</button>

</div>
```

y quiero obtener el valor del input que está inmediatamente antes del botón presionado, **¿cómo puedo hacerlo, tanto en jQuery como en Javascript?**

Por ejemplo, si presiono el `btnFour` quiero alcanzar a `ibxTwo`.

La idea es poder alcanzar el `input` para  poder modificar su valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun el boton presionado se tiene que buscar el **hermano previo mas cercano**  que sea de tipo 'INPUT'.

El tipo de elemento se verifica con `.nodeName`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.my-class button').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let inputCercano = getHermanosPrevious(el, 'INPUT');
    //console.log('hermano input mas cercano', inputCercano);
        console.log(`Javascript -> Botón presionado: ${el.id} \nValor del input adyacente: ${inputCercano.value}`);

  }))

function getHermanosPrevious(elem, tag) {

  while (elem = elem.previousSibling) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) continue;
    if (elem.nodeName == tag) {
      return elem;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <input id="ibxOne" type="text" value="test value" />
  <button id="btnOne" type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnTwo" type="submit">Action 2</button>
  <hr />
  <input id="ibxTwo" type="text" value="test value 2" />
  <button id="btnThree" type="submit">Action 1</button>
  <button id="btnFour " type="submit">Action 2</button>

</div>
```

Comment: ¡Genial! Justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera vas a obtener el ultimo input del document

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var elInput = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs).slice(-1);

console.log(elInput)
```

Comment: ¿El último `input` del documento?  Yo quiero el `input` más anterior al botón presionado, sabiendo que puede haber más inputs antes o después... Ahora edito la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.